# Django - adicionar usuario como membro da equipe na view

Tags: python, django, forms-authentication

Como permitir que um usuário ao se cadastrar já consiga se tornar membro da equipe pela própria view em Django?

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas nada aconteceu.

views.py:

```
def cadastro(request):
    form = ParticipanteForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParticipanteForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            request.user.is_staff = True
            return redirect('dashboard')

    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', locals())
```

Comment: como tá o seu models.py?

Comment: Oi. O meu models está assim:

```
class Participante(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email = models.EmailField()
    dt_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

```

Tem outros models, mas o que eu quero deixar como membro da equipe é esse models aí.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, esse comportamento desejado faz relação com o modelo já existente:

*.virtualenvs/nome_do_projeto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py*

Um dos modelos dentro desse arquivo python é o seguinte:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = True

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

O Django permite vc sobrescrever esse modelo padrão, mas vc precisará criar um app chamado *"usuarios"* e aí sim, no arquivo **models.py** desse app sobrescrever a função (app criado, a lista do settings deve ser atualizada)

```
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=True, #o Padrão é False
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
```

Mas vc vai copiar o arquivo e só modificar uma coisa nele?

Não... Um jeito mais fácil é vc herdar ele no modelo:

```
class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):
"""e aqui se atentar ao que pretende modificar"""
"""por exemplo, quer cadastrar email, nome e modificar a ação is_staff"""
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
```

Obviamente que como foi mudado o nome de um item "username" para nome e você pretende considerá-lo como campo de usuário, precisa informar:

```
class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nome' #aqui você indica o campo que predente usar como identificação do do namoe de usuário
```

Mas é só isso que pode fazer?
Não... se quiser ainda utilizar algumas outras opções padrão, pode acrescentar, por exemplo:

```
class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nome'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name'] #aqui você pode colocar outros campos que já existem no modelo padrão.
```

e terminar chamando o Manager

```
class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nome'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UsuarioManager() #aqui foi mudado o nome do modelo padrão
```

Esse é o primeiro passo.

O segundo é: como foram alterado algumas coisas, você precisa sobrescrever o Manager, e por isso, antes dessa classe recém escrita terá de praticamente copiar e colar o **UserManager(BaseUserManager)** que está no mesmo arquivo do **AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)** citado anteriormente:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nome'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UsuarioManager()
```

Mas é só isso?

Não, primeiro lembre-se que você (pra evitar conflitos), trocou o nome do Manager, então terá de trocar o nome da classe que acabou de copiar.

Você também trocou **username** por **nome** então precisa verificar todo o manager pra evitar problemas

Note também que você poderá retirar o campo **extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)** do create_user sabendo que é um usuário que auto-cadastrar-se-á (essa palavra é bonita... deve tá errada):

```
class UsuarioManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, **nome**, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        nome = self.model.normalize_username(nome)
        user = self.model(username=nome, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, nome, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class MeuUsuario(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField('nome', max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Funcionário', default=True)
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'nome'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UsuarioManager()
```

Acho que isso é tudo... pelo menos no que se refere à pergunta.

Aí você diz, mas eu tenho o meu formulário... o procedimento é o mesmo, como se fosse um model comum, a idéia aqui é modificar uma ação padrão do django pra daí vc manipular isso de acordo com a estética que achar mais conveniente.

=]

Comment: Ótima resposta, obrigada pela atenção e disposição!

Uma dúvida: é necessário eu criar outro app e fazer a modificação nele mesmo? Saberia me dizer o porquê disso acontecer e eu não poder fazer no meu app já em questão?

Comment: tá aí uma coisa que eu nunca testei... então prefiro não responder pra não confundir.

Comment: então, basta adicionar a linha `form.instance.is_staff = True`, antes do `form.save()`, na view. Deu certo! :D \o